# Parse single qouted dictionary key and value in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, string-parsing

I have a Python dictionary

```
original_dict={'body': '{"infra":["dev4","elk"],{"type":"file_integrity"}'}
```

I want to be able to parse original_dict keys and values as a normal dictionary which I am not able to do now because 'body' key has a a dictionary casted as string and therefore I am not refer to any of it's keys. So I should be able to say:

```
infra=original_dict['body]['infra']
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: use `json.loads` to convert the values, then access its values?

Comment: `json.loads(original_dict['body'])['infra']`

Comment: @cs95: Thanks for your help but I am not able to get it working.Here is my code and error as well:                                                                                                          import json 
original_dict={'body': '{"infra":["dev4","elk"],{"type":"file_integrity"}'}
print(json.loads(original_dict['body'])['infra'])                                                                               Error:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:Expecting property name enclosed in double  qouted

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, so it doesn't work. Try it with real valid JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing a curly brace in the original_dict.
Here is an example of converting a string into a dictionary.

```
    import json
    original_dict={'body':'{"infra":["dev4","elk"],"type":"file_integrity"}'}
    original_dict['body'] = json.loads(original_dict['body'])
    infra=original_dict['body']['infra']
    print(infra)
```

Output : ['dev4', 'elk']

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast too:)

```
import ast 
original_dict = {'body': '{"infra":["dev4","elk"],"type":"file_integrity"}'}
original_dict['body'] = ast.literal_eval(original_dict['body'])
```